# Given a string write a program to generate all possible strings by replacing ? with 0 and 1?

Tags: c, arrays, string, recursion, scanf

I have written this code it is working fine for a?b?c? and a?b?c?d? but for a?b?c?d?e? it is giving one additional garbage value at the end. At the end of s there is '\0' character attached then why and how is it reading that garbage value. I tried to debug it by placing printf statements in between the code but couldn't resolve it. please help.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void print(char* s,char c[],int l)
{
    int i,j=0;
    for(i=0;s[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
        if(s[i]=='?')
        {
            printf("%c",c[j]);
            j++;
        }
        else
            printf("%c",s[i]);
    }
    printf(", ");
}
void permute(char *s,char c[],int l,int index)
{
    if(index==l)
    {
        print(s,c,l);
        return;
    }
    c[index]='0';
    permute(s,c,l,index+1);
    c[index]='1';
    permute(s,c,l,index+1);
}
int main()
{
    char s[10],c[10];
    printf("Enter a string.");
    scanf("%s",s);
    int i,ct=0;
    for(i=0;s[i]!='\0';i++)
    {
        if(s[i]=='?')
            ct++;
    }
    permute(s,c,ct,0);
    return 0;
}
```

My output was like this :-

> a0b0c0d0e0♣, a0b0c0d0e1♣,

...and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As we can see from your code, with an array defined like `char s[10]` and the input being

> a?b?c?d?e?

is too *big* an input to be held in `s` along with the null-terminator by

```
 scanf("%s",s);
```

You need to use a bigger array. Otherwise, in attempt to add the terminating null after the input, the access is being made to out-of-bound memory which  invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

That said, never allow *unbound* input to the limited-sized array, always use the field-width to limit the input length (in other words, *reserve* the space for null-terminator), like

```
 scanf("%9s",s);
```

Comment: So should I go for malloc instead to avoid these kind of errors?

Comment: @Archana not necessary. Just make sure your input does not overflow the allocated buffer. Using field width is a good way to enforce the limit.

Comment: Devs. should stop byte-counting in all but RAM-restricted embedded environments.  If a user is going to enter a string, make it, say, 256 long.  It's quicker and safer to type '256' than counting bytes and making mistakes with array sizes.

Comment: I was just writing a comment about the overrun on the buffer when I scrolled down and you had already written it.

Comment: @Martin James I know its a bit late to ask but I didn't get what you meant by your comment 'all but RAM-restricted embedded environments.' if I understood correctly you just saying that using field width is good.?

Answer (score 1):

The code is producing the correct output here, but note that it has undefined behavior for strings of size greater than or equal to 10 chars, because that's the size of your buffer.

So, for `a?b?c?d?e?` you need a buffer of at least 11 characters, to account for the null terminator. You should make `s` bigger.

Answer (score 0):

See actually in C what happens in String is that everytime it appends a `'\0'` character at last.

Now notice in C there is nothing called string.

It's array of characters.

So if you have defined like this-

```
char s[10]
```

This actually accepts an array of less than of 9 characters as the last one will be the `'\0'` character.

If you add more than 9 character it will give erroneous output.